# Windows Phone 8.1. Async Methods works, but don't return the result

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, async-await

I have a little problem with async/await methods in a C# app for Windows Phone 8.1

I am creating a simple app for getting data from my service and save it on an user device.

I have got this code:

```
public static class ScheduleParser
{
    public static async Task<string> GetSchedule(string groupNumber)
    {
        string siteAddress = "site.com";
        siteAddress = string.Format(siteAddress, groupNumber);
        var client = new HttpClient();

        var response = await client.GetStringAsync(siteAddress);
        return response;
    }
  ...
  }
```

I use it in this way:

```
  private async void  ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       var schedule = await ScheduleParser.GetSchedule("1111111");
    }
```

I debug my app on a real device. When GetSchedule is called, I see that it works well and returns a value. But I don't receive the value in ButtonBase_OnClick.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `HttpClient` should be wrapped in a `using` so that it gets disposed when you're done.

Comment: What do you mean by *But I don't receive the value in ButtonBase_OnClick.* ?

Comment: ScheduleParser.GetSchedule("1111111") don't return any value

Comment: For a example, If I write code like this **var schedule = await ScheduleParser.GetSchedule("1111111"); doSomething()**  doSomething won't be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code that you showed you aren't actually using the result.  `schedule` is an unused variable.  Since the compiler can prove the value can never be read, it doesn't bother to create the variable in the first place.

When you actually *use the value* then you'll be able to see the result of the method call.

Comment: @I3arnon No, not only in release mode.  It's more aggressive in release mode, but it's an optimization that can also be taken in debug mode.

Comment: Everything in release mode can be done in debug mode. It's all just msbuild targets at the end. By default, it's a distinction between release mode and debug mode.

Comment: AFAIK this optimization will not be done in debug mode as it will make your debugging session painful. Also seen hans passant said somewhere in stackoverflow, can't find the link now.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I've personally seen it happen in debug mode.

Comment: @Servy May be you turned on optimize code checkbox in debug mode also? That will be turned off by default. (Edit: corrected typo)